# Python returning none instead of string output

Tags: python

I make some code about shrinking string in recursive function.

when input string is over it returns output.

it shows right thing in function but it returns None, instead of answer

```
def rec_encyption(input, i, cnt, output):
    if i + 1 == len(input):
        print(output)
        return output
    elif input[i] == input[i + 1]:
        rec_encyption(input, i + 1, cnt + 1, output)
    else:
        output = output + input[i] + str(cnt)
        rec_encyption(input, i + 1, 1, output)

def do_rec_encyption(input):
    n = rec_encyption(input + " ", 0, 1, "")
    print(n)
    return n

print(do_rec_encyption("aaabbcccccca"))
```

I run this code in VSCode and the result is this:

a3b2c6a1

None

None

which means `rec_encyption` return None, instead of 'output'

I can't find why and how to fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use return in else

```
def rec_encyption(input, i, cnt, output):
    if i + 1 == len(input):
        print(output)
        return output
    elif input[i] == input[i + 1]:
        return rec_encyption(input, i + 1, cnt + 1, output)
    else:
        output = output + input[i] + str(cnt)
        return rec_encyption(input, i + 1, 1, output)
```